# Detect/Manipulate An Element's CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

fiddle - http://jsbin.com/UsamELI/1/edit

I'm working on an experimental WYSIWYG web designer, and ran into a problem.
Originally I did this individually, but when I went back and looked at the code I thought I could narrow it down in a more simple and easier way to read while still performing it's task.

I have a div `.setmy-typography` that has a set of anchors in it with a title and text to state the font-family's name.

When I click on the canves/editor I can grab a div's class name in a textbox and begin manipulating it dynamically using the textbox as a holder for the class to easily manipulate.

I can detect the font and have it show up in a textbox without a problem using `$('.name').val($(this).css('font-family'));`

My problem is after the detection. If I detect arial, sans, or impact for example as the font. I want the backgroundColor to change on all the anchors but the font that's being used like arial for example I'm trying to detect the attr('title') or text() while also changing it's backgrounColor to show it's the active font and is currently selected.

Here's where I stopped

```
// Detect Font Family
if ($('.setmy-typography').find('a').text() === $(this).css('font-family')) {
  $('.setmy-typography a').css('backgroundColor', '#666');
  $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#1c1c1c');
}
```

This is a click event on the anchors with changes the chosen element's font size via the anchor's .text()

```
// Set selected elements font family
$('.grabmy-typography a').click(function() {
  $("." + $('.findclassname').val()).css({
    'font-family': $(this).text()
  });
  $('.grabmy-typography a').css('backgroundColor', '#444');
  $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#1c1c1c');
  $('.grab-font-family').val($(this).text());
});
```

I'm trying to create this type of effect but when the font-family has been detected once you click on an element in the canvas.

For closing I know I can do it individually (as that's what I started out doing before I processed further and further)

This is what the font-style detection looks like when done individually

```
// Detect Font Family
if ($(this).css('font-family') === 'serif') {
  $('.setmy-typography a').css('backgroundColor', '#444');
  $('.grab-serif').css('backgroundColor', '#1c1c1c');
}

if ($(this).css('font-family') === 'sans') {
  $('.setmy-typography a').css('backgroundColor', '#444');
  $('.grab-sans').css('backgroundColor', '#1c1c1c');
}

if ($(this).css('font-family') === 'arial') {
  $('.setmy-typography a').css('backgroundColor', '#444');
  $('.grab-arial').css('backgroundColor', '#1c1c1c');
}

if ($(this).css('font-family') === 'arial black') {
  $('.setmy-typography a').css('backgroundColor', '#444');
  $('.grab-arial-black').css('backgroundColor', '#1c1c1c');
}

if ($(this).css('font-family') === 'courier') {
  $('.setmy-typography a').css('backgroundColor', '#444');
  $('.grab-courier').css('backgroundColor', '#1c1c1c');
}

if ($(this).css('font-family') === 'comic sans ms') {
  $('.setmy-typography a').css('backgroundColor', '#444');
  $('.grab-comic-sans-ms').css('backgroundColor', '#1c1c1c');
}

if ($(this).css('font-family') === 'helvetica') {
  $('.setmy-typography a').css('backgroundColor', '#444');
  $('.grab-helvetica').css('backgroundColor', '#1c1c1c');
}

if ($(this).css('font-family') === 'impact') {
  $('.setmy-typography a').css('backgroundColor', '#444');
  $('.grab-impact').css('backgroundColor', '#1c1c1c');
}

if ($(this).css('font-family') === 'lucida sans') {
  $('.setmy-typography a').css('backgroundColor', '#444');
  $('.grab-lucida-sans').css('backgroundColor', '#1c1c1c');
}

if ($(this).css('font-family') === 'tahoma') {
  $('.setmy-typography a').css('backgroundColor', '#444');
  $('.grab-tahoma').css('backgroundColor', '#1c1c1c');
}

if ($(this).css('font-family') === 'times') {
  $('.setmy-typography a').css('backgroundColor', '#444');
  $('.grab-times-new-roman').css('backgroundColor', '#1c1c1c');
}

if ($(this).css('font-family') === 'times new roman') {
  $('.setmy-typography a').css('backgroundColor', '#444');
  $('.grab-times-new-roman').css('backgroundColor', '#1c1c1c');
}

if ($(this).css('font-family') === 'verdana') {
  $('.setmy-typography a').css('backgroundColor', '#444');
  $('.grab-verdana').css('backgroundColor', '#1c1c1c');
}
```

As you can see that's a bit if a headache and unnecessary. I'm sure there's an easier way, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just put all font-families and CSS properties in an array/object and loop over it:

```
var fontFamilyCSS = {
    'serif': {
        '.setmy-typography a': {
            'backgroundColor': '#444'
        }, 
        '.grab-serif': {
            'backgroundColor': '#1c1c1c'
        }
    }, 
    'sans': {
        '.setmy-typography a': {
            'backgroundColor': '#444'
        }, 
        '.grab-sans': {
            'backgroundColor': '#1c1c1c'
        }
    }
    // And so on
};
```

And then:

```
var css = fontFamilyCSS[$(this).css('font-family')] || false;

if (css) {
    for (var selector in css) {
        $(selector).css(css[selector]);
    }
}
```

Something like that. (Untested)

Edit: Actually, since the only difference between the font-families is that you're setting `.grab-FONT-FAMILY-NAME` you could probably do something like:

```
var fontFamily = $(this).css('font-family').toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '-');

$('.setmy-typography a').css('backgroundColor', '#444');
$('.grab-' + fontFamily).css('backgruondColor', '#1c1c1c');
```

Comment: I didn't even think about my difference with the class name. All I needed was 4 lines. Thanks - http://jsbin.com/UsamELI/2/edit